# How do I share USB VFAT Drive with other users?

Tags: usb, permissions

I want to share pictures between my wife and me, on an external USB drive. The OS is ubuntu 12.04. The drive is a Western Digital 500 GB and `sudo blkid /dev/sdc1` return `LABEL="My Book" UUID="9389-61cd" TYP="vfat"`

`ls -l /media` return `drwx------   ted ted 32768 Dec 31 1969 My Book`

(Ted is my account, and the account used to install Ubuntu 11.10, and upgrade to 12.04)

I want the access to be open to, at least, a common group, so preferred is `drwxrwxrwx`

This should automatically mount this way.

Comment: Those are not the permissions you want for group.

Comment: I may have posted too soon.

Comment: [link]https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions.   Links to a solution for mounting a partition for everyone to see.  I have followed the section labeled System Wide. I modified fstab with a line to mount the partition with group permission, and then added my wife to that group with sudo usermod -G ted deb       where ted is the name of the group created during installation, and deb is the user I wanted to modify.

Comment: You should consider making a separate group for this, so that `deb` doesn't have too much access to files owned by `ted`.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!